# When using onclick-event and document.write in javascript, does it always have to open in new window

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, document.write

Does it have to open in the sam
Eg:

function write(){
document.write("write")
}

input type="button" onclick="write()" value="Click"

Comment: I found this question via [Code is disappearing when I type in input element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54245217/4642212). This is similar code and it wouldn’t work, because the `write()` inside `onclick` calls `document.write` directly, _not_ the custom `write` function.

Answer (score 6):

document.write statements must be run before the page finishes loading

EDIT:  Therefore, you wouldn't want to put document.write into an onclick

If you're trying to modify a page already loaded you'll have to use div tags and use something like:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "bob";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't always have to open in a new window.

Now, if you'll be a lot more specific I can give you a better answer.